# Firebase Dynamic Link: Does not work correctly when opened from iOS Safari

Tags: firebase, mobile-safari, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase Dynamic Link in my app and am seeing issues when they are opened from iOS Safari as an URL.

-Expected behavior: The link leads to the app preview page, where the user can click on the link that will redirect to the app.

-Actual behavior: The link tries to open the preview page initially but loads the website even when the app is installed.

-The issue happens for both actual devices and simulators.

-The link works fine when opened from iOS Chrome as an URL, other iOS apps, and for all scenarios in Android devices/emulators.

I did my research but could find the exact same case as mine. Can someone tell me what might be the issue here so that I can investigate further?

Here is the Firebase Dynamic Link debugger result:

[image]

Here are the apple-app-site-association parameters:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"####.***.****","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

Can someone help out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might run into a similar issue, I resolved this by disabling forced redirects in the link parameter. Somehow mobile Safari was force redirecting to the website, not the app.